# react-navigation Screen that conceals TabBar from nested StackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm new to `react-navigation` and trying to wrap my head around how to do the following:

Given this navigation structure:

```
RootTabNavigator 

  LoggedOut_StackNavigator

    ...

  LoggedIn_StackNavigator

    LoggedIn_TabNavigator <-- TabBar rendered by this Navigator

      TabA_StackNavigator

        ScreenA
        ScreenB
```

I would like to be able to navigate from `ScreenA` to `ScreenB` using the typical "slide in from right" transition, in such a way that the `TabBar` **is** visible on `ScreenA`, but is **not** visible on `ScreenB`. In other words, when I navigate to `ScreenB`, I want it to take up the entire window.

Once the user transitions from `ScreenA` to `ScreenB`, they can either press the back button to return back to `ScreenA`, or navigate to new routes using the same transition with the `TabBar` still **not** visible.

**What I've tried:**

- `navigationOptions.tabBarVisible`: this property only seems to work when applied to `TabA_StackNavigator` itself, which means that **all** of the screens in its stack also conceal the `TabBar`. Adding it to the screens inside the StackNavigator has no effect.
- Adding a new `AllScreens_StackNavigator` as a sibling of `LoggedIn_TabNavigator` and navigating to routes inside this navigator, I get the error: `Expect nav state to have routes and index, {"routeName":"ScreenB", "params": {}, "key": "init-id-1516..."}`. The navigation action I dispatched to try to do this:

  ```
  {
    "action": Object {
      "params": Object {},
      "routeName": "ScreenB",
      "type": "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
    },
    "params": Object {},
    "routeName": "AllScreens_StackNavigator",
    "type": "Navigation/NAVIGATE",
  }
  ```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you please post code for your navigator?

Comment: To achieve what you want, you should push your new route to the navigator of LoggedIn_StackNavigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: this answer is relevant to `react-nagivation` v1.~ (pre v2.0)**

As suggested in the comments, see this issue:

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/issues/19

---

Apparently, the `navigationOptions` of an inner component affect the containing navigator's parent navigator as well.

### Solution

That means this code should work for you:

```
class ScreenB extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: () => null,  //this will hide the Stack navigator's header (TabA_StackNavigator)
    tabBarVisible: false //this will hide the TabBar navigator's header (LoggedIn_TabNavigator)
  }
```

### Explanation

**First,** you can set the navigation options per individual screen (component). You can see how in the code snippet above or here: [React Navigation - Screen Navigation Options](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Two-Ways-to-specify-each-option)

**Second,** you tried:

> Adding it to the screens inside the StackNavigator has no effect.

It didn't work because hiding the StackNavigator's header requires setting the `header` field to `null`.

From the [React Navigation documentation:](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#header)

> React Element or a function that given HeaderProps returns a React
>   Element, to display as a header. **Setting to null hides header**

**Third,** using [tabBarVisible](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarVisible) is actually correct, but it affects only the TabNavigator. And to make it disappear only for one tab and not for all the tabs, you need to set it on the specific screen. `ScreenB` in your case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the time you posted I had already figured it out and I haven't had a chance to try your solution. I solved it differently, and will post my solution. After a few more people vote on what's worked for them I'll mark a solution correct. Thanks again :)

Comment: This solution no longer works for react-navigation v2;
See here for a working solution: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/issues/19#issuecomment-387885810

Answer (score 0):

The following is what ended up working for me, so I'm posting it the hopes that it helps others. I haven't had a chance to try `@talzaj`'s implementation so I'll leave it up to others to upvote whatever works best for them. The following solution has been working well for me, including inside nested navigators.

I updated my navigation structure such that:

1. `LoggedIn_StackNavigator` still has `LoggedIn_TabNavigator` as one of its screens, and this `LoggedIn_TabNavigator` is the initial route of `LoggedIn_StackNavigator` as set using `initialRouteName`.
2. `LoggedIn_StackNavigator` also contains a route for **every screen that will ever need to be shown full screen and conceal the tab bar**. (If you are re-using screens, where some are shown with the tab bar visible and others where it is not, **make sure to use unique keys** for routes that re-use the same screen.

### Navigation Structure

So, the navigation structure looks like:

```
RootTabNavigator 

  LoggedOut_StackNavigator

  LoggedIn_StackNavigator

    ScreenA // ( reuse screen component, different route key )

    ScreenB // ( reuse screen component, different route key )

    LoggedIn_TabNavigator <-- TabBar rendered by this Navigator

      TabA_StackNavigator

        ScreenA
        ScreenB
```

### `LoggedIn_StackNavigator`:

And `LoggedIn_StackNavigator` looks like:

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LoggedIn_TabNavigator from './LoggedIn_TabNavigator';
import { 
  ScreenA, 
  ScreenB, 
} from './LoggedIn_TabNavigator/TabA_StackNavigator/Screens';

const LoggedIn_StackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  WithoutTabBar_ScreenA: {
     screen: ScreenA
  },
  WithoutTabBar_ScreenB: {
    screen: ScreenB
  },
  LoggedIn_TabNavigator: {
    screen: LoggedIn_TabNavigator
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'LoggedIn_TabNavigator'
});

export default LoggedIn_StackNavigator;
```

From there, I wrote a helper HOC for pushing full screen routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import { fullScreenRoutePrefix } from './somewhere';

export default function withNavigateFullScreen(Child) {

  @withNavigation
  class WithNavigateFullScreenHOC extends React.Component {

    navigateToFullScreenRoute = (routeName, params) => {          
      this.props.navigation.navigate(
        `${fullScreenRoutePrefix}${routeName}`, params
      );
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Child 
          {...this.props} 
          navigateFullScreen={this.navigateToFullScreenRoute} 
        />
      );
    }
  }
  return WithNavigateFullScreenHOC;
}
```

And then I can navigate to full screen routes like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withNavigateFullScreen } from 'components/higher-order';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

@withNavigateFullScreen
export default class ScreenA extends React.Component {
  goToScreenB = () => {
    this.props.navigateFullScreen('ScreenB');
  }
  render() {
    return <Text onPress={this.goToScreenB}>Go To Screen B</Text>;
  }
}
```